# android No Firebase app '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp(), js engine: hermes error in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I m trying to integrate google firebase to my react native project and im getting the above error.Here are my config files
This is my gradles

my build.gradle file contents are as below

```
    dependencies {
            classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
            classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
            classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0")
            classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9")
        }
```

this is my app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")
apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```